# Background importing of slow python module

Tags: odoo, python-multithreading, python-module

I have a python module (`odoo.py`) that creates a connection with an Odoo instance.

```py
import odoorpc
from .env import ENV

ODOO = odoorpc.ODOO(ENV["ODOO_HOST"], port=ENV["ODOO_PORT"])
ODOO.login(db=ENV["ODOO_DB"], login=ENV["ODOO_USR"], password=ENV["ODOO_PWD"])
```

`ODOO` constant is imported by several modules containing Mongoengine classes to perform operations on the Odoo server. Here is an example:

```py
from mongoengine import *
from .odoo import ODOO


class Category(DynamicDocument):
    name = StringField(required=True)
    odoo_id = StringField()

    def publish(self):
        _model = ODOO.env["product.category"]
        self.odoo_id = _model.create({"name": self.name})
        self.save()
```

Problem is that importing `odoo.py` takes about 10 seconds during application startup and it's REALLY annoying in development.

Let's consider this pseudo `main.py`:

```py
import sys
from .category import Category

cat = Category(name=sys.argv[1])
if not 'test' in cat.name:
    cat.publish()
```

In this example if `sys.argv[1]` contains the string 'test' then `ODOO` constant will never be used and waiting for its import would be totally useless.

Is there a way to "background" importing of `odoo.py` and wait for it only when `ODOO` constant is actually needed?